# Using Modernizr in Angular unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, modernizr

I have an Angular app defined within a Grails gsp. The Modernizr library is included at the gsp level.

I need to use the library within a directive unit test. Since I don't have Modernizr defined as a module since it's used outside of the Angular app as well as inside it, how do I inject it into my Angular unit test?

Here's my directive:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('simplify.directives').directive('img', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (elem, attrs) {
            if ( typeof Modernizr !== 'undefined' && !Modernizr.svg ) {
                $timeout(function(){
                    elem.attr('src', attrs.src.replace('.svg', '.png'));
                });
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Here's my unit test code:

```
'use strict';

describe('Testing SVG to PNG directive', function() {
    var scope,
        elem;

    beforeEach(module('app'));

    beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
        $provide.service('appConstants', function(){});
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
        elem = angular.element('<img ng-src="test-img.svg" />');
        scope = $rootScope;
        $compile(elem)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('Should swap svg for png image if svg is not supported', function() {
       //force Modernizr.svg to be undefined here for purposes of the test
        expect(elem.attr('src')).toBe('test-img.png');
    });

});
```

What's the best-practice way to do this?

Comment: Inject `$window` in your directive and get modernizer from `$window.Modernizr`. And mock modernizer for your testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by updating the directive to inject `$window` and get `Modernizr` instance from `$window`.

i.e:-

```
.directive('img', ['$timeout','$window', function ($timeout, $window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

            if ( typeof $window.Modernizr !== 'undefined' && !$window.Modernizr.svg ) {
                $timeout(function(){
                    elem.attr('src', attrs.src.replace('.svg', '.png'));
                });
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

In your test just create a mock Modernizr and since you are using `$timeout` you would need to flush the `timeout` by doing `$timeout.flush()` inorder for timeout callback to get executed.

```
describe('Testing SVG to PNG directive', function() {
    var scope,
        elem, 
        ModernizerMock = {svg:false};// <-- use this for mocking various conditions

    beforeEach(module('app'));

    beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
        $provide.service('appConstants', function(){});
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope, $timeout, $window) {
        elem = angular.element('<img ng-src="test-img.svg" />');
        scope = $rootScope;
        $window.Modernizr = ModernizerMock; //Set the mock
        $compile(elem)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
        $timeout.flush(); //<-- Flush the timeout
    }));

    it('Should swap svg for png image if svg is not supported', function() {
       //force Modernizr.svg to be undefined here for purposes of the test
          expect(elem.attr('src')).toBe('test-img.png');
    });
});
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nN3DxYIH1SkipjCPxGZc?p=preview)**

and had your directive been like this:

```
.directive('img', ['$window', function ($window) {
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          compile: function (elem, attrs) {
            if ( typeof $window.Modernizr !== 'undefined' && !$window.Modernizr.svg ) {
               attrs.$set('ngSrc', attrs.ngSrc.replace('.svg', '.png'));
            }
          }
      };
 }]);
```

It would be lesser effort to test with the absence of timeout logic. **[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4WNNwMi3Afv03wNEiEtO?p=preview)**

Comment: Another great in-depth answer. Thanks for the second day in a row!